# Does an understanding of how the Bible was written, play a strong role in any Christian sect?

Tags: history

There is sometimes a misunderstanding or differing opinion of who wrote what in the Bible.  Is this issue relevant to any particular Christian sect?  Does the topic play an important role?

Comment: Could you give an example of a book of the Bible where this is the case?  In most cases, there is either an author whose actual "authorship" is or is not in question (Pauline vs. Deuero-Pauline, Moses vs. JEPD) but other than Hebrews (for which there is no author) I can't think of a case where there is actually a different named author that would have any effect.

Comment: Peter may not have written this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Epistle_of_Peter

Comment: Did my response not answer your question? I can expand or clarify if you need.

Comment: @Drew It did.  Thanks.  I was just waiting to see if there would be other responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Catholic, you study the books of the bible taking into account to whom the books were written.

The Catholic faith is based on Scripture and Tradition (with a capital 'T'). We realize that in the early church, many things were passed down by word of mouth. In other words from the Catechism of the Catholic Church:

> 82      As a result the Church, to whom the transmission and interpretation of Revelation is entrusted, “does not derive her certainty about all revealed truths from the holy Scriptures alone. Both Scripture and Tradition must be accepted and honored with equal sentiments of devotion and reverence.”44

As far as I can tell, there is not great importance placed on who specifically wrote a book, but the author is taken into account while reading the scripture.

Comment: Furthermore, the Church deems the historical context, genre, and intended audience as very important considerations for proper interpretation.

Comment: For additional comment on the 'T'radition that I mentioned, see the [Catechism of the Catholic Church 83](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__PL.HTM)

Answer (score 1):

For most Protestants the answer would be the same as for Catholics, as set out in Andrew's excellent answer.

Understanding of the Bible should include an understanding of the context in which it was written, including the author, the intended audience, and the situation in which both of those existed.

Evangelical denominations do place an emphasis on the belief that the "traditional" attributions of authorship are correct, for example that the Gospel of Matthew was in fact written by Matthew the Apostle.